# Use TypeScript to trigger a compile error when BigNumber.toString is used?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bignum

Is it possible to use TypeScript to trigger a compile-time error if `BigNumber.toString` is called?

Specifically, my application has experienced bugs because `BigNumber.toString()` will express sufficiently large and sufficiently small numbers in scientific notation:

```
> x = new BigNumber('0.00000000001')
> x.toString()
'1e-10'
> x.toFixed()
'0.00000000001'
```

I've tried overriding the type:

```
import {BigNumber} from "bignumber.js";

declare module "bignumber.js" {
  interface BigNumber {
    toString: never
    someOtherThing: number
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work (and the `someOtherThing` field is added, so I know the type definitions are being loaded)

How can I trigger a compile error if `BigNumber.toString` is used?

(also, note: I have set `BigNumber.config({ EXPONENTIAL_AT: 1e+9 })` and overloaded `BigNumber.toString` so it issues a warning, but it would be nice to have the added compile error)

Comment: I can't follow your  code.. you're importing `BigNumber`, but then are immediately declaring the same name as an interface. This should not be allowed to compile. I get you're trying to override the type, but I don't expect this is how that should be done. Please, correct me if I am wrong, I'd love to learn if that's the case.

I'd make my own class that uses BigNumber, wraps the methods, and returns `''` for the`toString` method.

Comment: @StevenStark that's the TypeScript syntax for extending an interface (scroll to "Augmenting"): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that was just a TS convention. I've been using Flow exclusively these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use TypeScript to trigger a compile-time error if BigNumber.toString is called

Few options

## Create a custom linter rule

Docs on tslint : https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/ 
You custom rule would be type checking rule : https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/type-checking/

And change `toString` invocations on `BigNumber` to be an error.

## Edit the types on install

Remove the `toString` method from BigNumber by editing the installed `.d.ts` and commit it using PatchPackage : https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

## Create a wrapper

Alternatively create a wrapper around BigNumber that doesn't expose anything you consider dangerous to your fellow developers

## Thoughts

I would personally use patch package as its the easier route. If you are doing a lot of financial work with the library then consider a wrapper for your use case.

Comment: As an alternative to patching the package, it's also possible to monkeypatch the library at runtime: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/issues/185#issuecomment-435071867)